# ListView always scrolls back to the top in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I am using `react-native` for a iOS mobile app where I am using `ListView` to display a list of alarms. I have created my own reusable list view component called `ComponentListView` in which I can pass in the component that I want to render in each row and the data for the list view. If I have a lot of alarms and I scroll down to see the alarms in the end, it always scrolls back to the top (please see sample app below on rnplay with symptoms) and hence I can't operate on the alarms in the end. I think it may have something to do with how I have created the `ComponentListView` component because if I just use a simple `ListView` component, it works as expected but I need to use `ComponentListView` component since I have many different screens where I have to display a list with different component and it simplifies my work.

I have created a sample app on rnplay which shows these symptoms. Please run on iOS. Here `AlarmList` is using `ComponentListView` to show a list of alarms and `AlarmSummary` is the component displayed in each row.

[Sample app on rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/9edB9g)

I try to debug it using some console log statements in the render method of the ComponentListView to check if the component is getting re-rendered again and again on scrolling but that doesn't seem to be the case. I also tried to debug in Chrome debugger but I am kind of out of ideas and not sure how/where to debug.

Please let me know if you have any pointers to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give `flex: 1` attribute to the `sceneContainer` also, like:

```
sceneContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  marginTop: 60
},
```

Working here: https://rnplay.org/apps/TL9N9g

Comment: Thanks, your answer fixed the problem but I am still don't understand completely how not having `flex: 1` caused the scroll to not work properly. I understand that `flex: 1` will allow the container to use all the available space. If I don't have `flex: 1` it will only use required space. Is it because not having `flex: 1` was causing the container to go out of bounds and hence scroll was not actually required? Do you mind shedding some light on it if you have some more insights?

Comment: @VarunGupta , from docs: *In order to bound the height of a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height. Forgetting to transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which the element inspector makes easy to debug.* , link: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.25/docs/scrollview.html#content

Answer (score 0):

For simple clarity: you need to set the height of the ListView itself **OR** set the height of the container/parent element using an explicit "height" value or by setting "flex" in the  style.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <ListView />
</View>
```

---

```
<View>
   <ListView style={{height:300}} />
</View>
```