# NativeBase (React Native) avoid scrolling back to top

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use the List component to handle a lot of inputs, but notice that it keeps scrolling back to top after entering the input.

[image]

Don't know if this is related to [ListView always scrolls back to the top in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234317/listview-always-scrolls-back-to-the-top-in-react-native) - I have tried to `<List style={{flex> 1}} ..>` but no luck..

## UPDATE

Thought it might be more easy to help me out if I throw in some code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { List, ListItem,  InputGroup, Input, Icon, Button } from 'native-base'

export default class AddInformation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      items: 
[
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
{value: "", keyboardType: "default"}]}

}

render () {
    return (
      <List
        dataArray={this.state.items}
        renderRow={
          (obj) => {
            console.log(obj)
            return (
              <ListItem>
                <InputGroup>

                <Input
                  placeholder={`${obj.keyboardType} keyboard`}
                  onChangeText={ (text)=> {
                    //TODO
                  } }
                  keyboardType={obj.keyboardType}
                />
                </InputGroup>
              </ListItem>
            )
        }}>
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

## UPDATE 2

Still not working..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, ListView, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { FormLabel, FormInput } from 'react-native-elements'

export default class AddInformation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

  }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.state = {
      items: ds.cloneWithRows([
        {hint: "foo", value: "", keyboardType: "default"},
         ...
        {hint: "bar", value: "", keyboardType: "numeric"}
      ])
    }

  }
...
```

And the render method:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ListView

          dataSource={this.state.Specifications}
          renderRow={(rowData) =>
            <View>
              <FormLabel>{rowData.hint}</FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                placeholder={`Keyboard: ${rowData.keyboardType}`}
                />
                <TextInput />
            </View>
          }/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Don't know if it has something to do with with the NativeBase layout..?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Content, Header, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base'
import AddInformation from './AddInformation'

export default class ScreenAddItemInformation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>

        <Header>
          <Button transparent onPress={ () => this.props.navigator.pop() }>
            <Icon name='ios-backspace' />
          </Button>

          <Title>Add New Item</Title>

        </Header>

        <Content>
          <AddInformation />
        </Content>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

## UPDATE 3

I just tried out with a NB `<List>` of hard coded `<ListItem>` and no dynamic rendering.. It's still the issue that once the keyboard goes down the "view" scrolls back to the top.

Comment: do you have the `rowHasChanged` properly implemented so that it won't render the already rendered rows?

Comment: @TudorConstantin no I do not. I'm using NativeBase Dynamic List http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#list that's only supposed to pass an array.

Comment: Can you add your code where you update this.state.items . Tudor comment seems to be correct. You should try using ListView directly instead of List widget. Depending how you are setting items state, ListView might be re rendering whole list again through List widget.

Comment: @while1 I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the same question to [NB forum](http://discuss.nativebase.io/t/list-and-input-avoid-scrolling-back-to-top/192), I got a useful link to a way to solve this "bug":

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/339

**Components/ScreenAddInformation.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Content, Header, Title, Button, Icon } from 'native-base'
import Information from './Information'

export default class ScreenAddInformation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {scrollY: 0}
  }

handleScroll(event) {
    this.setState({ scrollY: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y });
  }

  render() {
    _.set(this.refs, 'Content._scrollview.resetCoords', { x: 0, y: this.state.scrollY });
    return (
      <Container>

        <Header>
          <Button transparent onPress={ () => this.props.navigator.pop() }>
            <Icon name='ios-backspace' />
          </Button>

          <Title>Add New Information</Title>

        </Header>

        <Content
          ref="Content"
          onScroll={event => this.handleScroll(event)}
          >
          <AddInformation />
        </Content>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**Components/AddInformation.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { List, ListItem, InputGroup, Input } from 'native-base'

export default class AddInformation extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem itemDivider>
          <Text>Information to add</Text>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem >
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Foo" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem >
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Foo" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem >
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Foo" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem >
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Foo" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem >
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Foo" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem >
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Foo" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <InputGroup borderType="underline">
            <Input stackedLabel label="Bar" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

And the working solution is here:

[image]

I'm so glad it works now! thx booboothefool

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.. Does it still work for you on the latest versions of the libs?

Comment: I sorta went away from nativebase a while ago... So wouldn't know, sorry

Comment: No worries thanks anyway! Any reason why you moved away from it?

Comment: It's great but still too much beta for me. A lot of things changed in version 2 and I would like to wait for it to become a bit more stable - I definitely expect to come back. I learned to build some of the component myself (like cards)..

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue as well, and this proved to be a simple workaround for me.

```
<Container>
    <ScrollView>{/* <- Use this rather than Content */}
      {/* form with this issue */}
    </ScrollView>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just hide the keyboard on submit? Try a workaround like this:

```
<TextInput onSubmitEditing={ () => Keyboard.dismiss() }>
```

Don't forget to import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

Comment: Thank for a good suggestion, but will it work if I press outside (on the list) and the keyvboard goes down? Is that the same - because I only see an onFocus prop and not an offFocus

Comment: You can also add an onBlur to the TextInput , which is the opposite of onFocus.